# How can I get ASP.Net version in IIS through C#?

Tags: iis

I want to specify the default document and the asp.net version for an virtual directory through C#

For default document I have wrote the code as

```
 "deVDir.Properties["DefaultDoc"].Value = "Mainscreen1.aspx";
```

and i am not able to get the property name for ASP.NET VERSION  which will be given as "2.0.50727".

can anybody guide me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using IIS 6. In IIS 6 there is no way to set the ASP.NET version by setting a single property.

What you need to do is set the script maps for the ASP.NET extensions (`.aspx`, `.asmx` and so on) to the following path:

> `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll`